# How to transpile typescript with imported modules to a browser friendly js-file

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules, es6-modules, transpiler

I am struggling with transpiling ts for some time now. I have an npm package with typescript files and some node_modules all linked together.

```
// example.ts
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
export default () => {
    const popoverList = document.querySelectorAll('.popover');
    popoverList.foreach((popover) => {
        new bootstrap.Popover(popover)
    })
}
```

And in another file:

```
// maint.ts
import initPopovers from './example';

initPopovers();
```

And off course a lot more in and exports. The problem is that i want this entrypoint (main.ts) to be transpiled to main.js and all the files included from node_modules baked into it. No modules anymore but just plain old js that works out of the box in the browser.
I tried many different things but none of them worked. The best one was browserify but with Typescript this did not work as expected.

Does someone have the solution for me?

Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to answer this, but I realized that I need to see the packages your using to offer any suggestions. There is a couple of options, one you mentioned, which is browserfy (and if I knew more, I might be able to make suggestions on how to get it to work) babel also tends to be more useful for niche cases like this as far as transpilers go (in this case I am thinking of the package for babel boot-loader). Unfortunatly the best option is usually a mono repo. Mono-repos are more work, but they are generally the most robust, solid, & most scalable solution.

Comment: Really though, it all depends on the packages, how many packages, and the size of the packages. I suggest updating your question to include all of your non-dev dependencies, your package.json file, and the configuration your using to transpile your project with. TypeScript can emit the whole project to a single file, but you would have to add your dependencies as local imports (as files that sit in your `./src/lib`dir), and allow your project to use JS. Again though, I need more to go on to advise you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `tsup` works for you? It's based on `esbuild` and should do exactly that:
https://github.com/egoist/tsup .

What you're looking for is called a `bundler` (along with a transpiler), there are several others.

Comment: Ended up using esbuild on its own. Does exactly what i needed. Many thanks!